# Problema al unir 2 PDF, trabajo con Reportlab y uso Python 3.8,

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy tratando de unir 2 PDF, con Python 3.8, uno como marco de agua y el otro donde imprimo el reporte, mi problema es que realiza el proceso en ambas páginas, ósea, dibuja lo mismo en la primera y segunda página, he investigado en la red y no doy con la respuesta, no logro ver cuál es mi error, si me pudieran orientar, se los agradecería.

Importaciones

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
```

Antes genero un PDF, sin problema, aquí, quiero unirlo a la marca de agua y lo que hace es imprimir todo en una página y luego lo repite en la segunda.

```
#   archivo que acabo de generar
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(file_name)
# leer PDF marca de agua
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("informe_medico_opcion1.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
# agregue la "marca de agua" (que es el nuevo pdf) en la página existente
page_count = new_pdf.getNumPages()
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
for i in range(page_count):
    page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(i))
    output.addPage(page)
# finalmente, escribe "salida" en un archivo real
outputStream = open("Informe_Consulta.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

chrome_path = 'c:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
wb.get(chrome_path).open_new(r"c:/oftica/Informe_Consulta.pdf")
```

Ejemplo de como imprime, monta la primera página sobre la segunda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alguien tendra alguna idea del problema, se lo agradeceria, saludos y gracias de antemano.